# How to display a default image if original image is not available?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

on my view I am using this code, I want to display Equipment Image, but in-case there is no original image is uploaded, i want to display a defult image (NoImage.jpg), but Default Image is not displaying...

```
  @if (item.EquipImage != null)
          {
         <td><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/EquipImages/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.EquipImage))" alt="" width="70" height="70"/> </td>
          }else
          {
               <td><img src="@Server.MapPath("~/Content/EquipImages/NoImage.jpg")" alt="" width="70" height="70"/> </td>
          }
```

=====================================================================
with the help of Jsmith and Json the code is working.. I am pasting here the working code which could be helpful for some one :)

```
 @if(! string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.EquipImage)){

            <td><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/EquipImages/" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item.EquipImage))" alt="" width="70" height="70"/> </td>
            }else{
               <td><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/EquipImages/NoImage.jpg")" alt="" width="70" height="70"/> </td>
          }
```

Comment: Why are you using `Server.MapPath` for the default image and not `Url.Content`? Use `Url.Content` instead and that should fix the problem. If it does not, then check that image does exist at the path you have specified, but pasting the path into the url of the browser and pressing enter. Or use Fiddler, or browser dev tools, to help you.

Comment: I would also suggest using !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.EquipImage) instead of item.EquipImage != null

Comment: perfect, its working now

Comment: how to tag your comment as answer @Jason Evans

Comment: I've pasted my text into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using Server.MapPath for the default image and not Url.Content? Use Url.Content instead and that should fix the problem.

If it does not, then check that image does exist at the path you have specified, but pasting the path into the url of the browser and pressing enter. Or use Fiddler, or browser dev tools, to help you